# Unable to apply style to my grid after creating a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the following grid. If you click on any of the cell of `Link` column, a new grid below will be generated.

And whenever I try to add css style using the following line in the code `document.getElementById("commonWindow").style.padding = "50px 10px 20px 30px";` below, it keeps on throwing error (`"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`). However, if you comment it out, it works fine. I am basically trying to add more space between the first grid and the newly created grid which gets created everytime I click on any of the cell value of Link column.

```js
  // prepare the data
    var url = "https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/sampledata/feed.xml";
    var source =
    {
        datatype: "xml",
        datafields: [
            { name: 'title', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'link', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'pubDate', type: 'date' },
            { name: 'creator', map: 'dc\\:creator', type: 'string' },
       ],
        root: "channel",
        record: "item",
        url: url
    };
    var linkrenderer = function (row, column, value) {
        if (value.indexOf('#') != -1) {
            value = value.substring(0, value.indexOf('#'));
        }
        var format = { target: '"_blank"' };
        var html = $.jqx.dataFormat.formatlink(value, format);
        //console.log(html)
        return html;
    }
    var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
    
    var cellsrenderer = function (row, column, value) {
        var currentRowData = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('getrowdata', row);
        var rowDataLink = currentRowData["link"];

        return "<a href =" + rowDataLink + ">" + value + "</a>";
    };
        
        
    // Create jqxGrid.
    $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
        width: 850,
        source: dataAdapter,
        pageable: true,
        autoheight: true,
        sortable: true,
        columns: [
          { text: 'Link', datafield: 'link', width: 550},
          { text: 'Title', datafield: 'title', width: 200, cellsrenderer: cellsrenderer },
          { text: 'Publish Date', datafield: 'pubDate', width: 250, cellsformat: "D" },
          { text: 'Creator', datafield: 'creator', width: 200 }
       ]
    });
    
     $("#jqxgrid").on("rowselect", function (e) {

        let link = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('getcell', e.args.rowindex, 'link');
        console.log(link.value);
        $('#commonWindow').remove();
     var elem = document.createElement('div');
     elem.id = 'commonWindow';
        document.getElementById("commonWindow").style.padding = "50px 10px 20px 30px";
        
        $(elem).jqxGrid({
            source: dataAdapter, columns: [
                { text: 'Link', datafield: 'link', width: 550 },
                { text: 'Title', datafield: 'title', width: 200, cellsrenderer: cellsrenderer },
                { text: 'Publish Date', datafield: 'pubDate', width: 250, cellsformat: "D" },
                { text: 'Creator', datafield: 'creator', width: 200 }
            ] });
        document.body.appendChild(elem);
     });
```

```html
<div id="jqxgrid">
        </div>
<link href="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/jqx-all.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time your code hits the following line:

```
document.getElementById("commonWindow").style.padding = "50px 10px 20px 30px";
```

...you haven't actually appended the element to the DOM yet, therefore the DOM cannot find the element when you ask for it by using `document.getElementById`.

The place you actually add the element to the DOM comes later:

```
document.body.appendChild(elem);
```

Instead, you should reference the element directly using `elem`, like you do elsewhere in your code, like this:

```
elem.style.padding = "50px 10px 20px 30px";
```

However all that said, it might make the most sense of all to just include the padding rule as a static style in your CSS instead of adding it to your JavaScript like this.

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for an element with id `commonWindow` in document before putting it there. It's not there yet so you are getting `null`.

Also when you already have reference to the element in the variable `elem`, you can set style directly to it. You don't need to search document for it.

```
$("#jqxgrid").on("rowselect", function (e) {
    let link = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('getcell', e.args.rowindex, 'link');
    console.log(link.value);
    $('#commonWindow').remove();

    var elem = document.createElement('div');
    elem.id = 'commonWindow';

    document.body.appendChild(elem);
    elem.style.padding = "50px 10px 20px 30px";

    $(elem).jqxGrid({
        source: dataAdapter,
        columns: [
            { text: 'Link', datafield: 'link', width: 550 },
            { text: 'Title', datafield: 'title', width: 200, cellsrenderer: cellsrenderer },
            { text: 'Publish Date', datafield: 'pubDate', width: 250, cellsformat: "D" },
            { text: 'Creator', datafield: 'creator', width: 200 }
        ]
    });
});
```